# Replication Delay on a Postgres Streaming Replication Standby

Tags: postgresql

I have a primary postgres database replicating to two standby by streaming replication.One of the standby is experiencing replication delay. I check the logs on the standby, I do not see any errors. I check the status of the startup process on the standby. It shows it is waiting on a wal file and the same wal file for hours. I am not sure if it is long running queries that is causing the issue or something else.

```
ps -ef | grep startup
postgres   733   731  2 Apr26 ?        1-17:08:15 postgres: startup recovering 00000001000168C1000000D7 waiting
postgres 28915  4756  0 16:46 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto startup
```

I check the status of the startup process on the other replica, it is replicating just fine

Comment: It isn't waiting on a WAL file.  It is waiting on *something else*, while recovering at a specific WAL location.  Yes, it is probably log running queries on that standby.